# Plotting a single column data frame in real-time

Tags: python

I have a single column data frame constantly collecting data from an external device running in a while loop in real time. In order to plot the data frame I have used `tkinter` but due to its resource intensive issues I abandoned it, I have tried using `matplotlib`, but couldn't get it to update accordingly.
Any other suggestions or an example would be great

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found some help online and managed to neatly and efficiently display the data incoming from my sensors. So here are my steps to achieve the result, Open the python command window, and type `python YourDataretrievingScript.py` this will run your script of retrieving data from your sensors, just make sure you save it onto a csv file, then I run the following code and the animation window pops up

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator







plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
index = count()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('Predict.csv')
    
    
    x1 = data['Target']
    x2 = data['Gesture']
    
    
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x1, label = 'Positions')
    plt.plot(x2, label = 'Gesture')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()
    
  
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval = 500)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have plotted two different columns of data of the same csv file, and removed the xticks as per my specifications, if you don't want that just remove the `plt.xticks([])`